# Responsive navigation bar closes when opened

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, navigation

So I made a site a long time ago and now wanted to incorporate a responsive menu into it. Problem is that when I click on the menu bar it opens but then closes immediately after it reveals the whole list.

Menu HTML:

```
<!-- start menu -->
 <div id="menu" class="fix-fish-menu">
    <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_list.php">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="showrooms_list.php">Showrooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="services_list.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="bookmarks.php">Bookmarks</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php">Fashion 101</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>  <!-- end #nav  -->
    <div class="menu-trigger">
        MODASearch <span>The Fashion Directory</span> <i class="fa fa-bars "></i>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- end #menu  -->
```

CSS:

```
.menu-trigger{
    background-color: #39414c;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    clear:both;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}
.menu-trigger span{ 
    font-size:12px; 
}
.menu-trigger i{
    font-size:18px;
    float:right;
}
```

responsive.css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .menu-trigger{display:block;}
    #nav {display:none; }
    .nav-expanded{display:block;}
}
```

linked JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
        jQuery("#nav").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('overflow','');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Its working fine. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/3ckc2etz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, actually had some help, but the problem was that a class cannot override an ID rule in this fashion, so the content resets back to display none as soon as the jQuery animation completes.

So in this case i added another class to the #nav element and set display hidden to it rather than hiding the id. Works fine now. Sorry have never used jsfiddle before otherwise i would have posted the answer there too. Special thanks to Brad Schiff for pointing me in the right direction.

here is how the code looks now:

```
 <div id="menu" class="fix-fish-menu">
    <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu my-menu">
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_list.php">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="showrooms_list.php">Showrooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="services_list.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="bookmarks.php">Bookmarks</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php">Fashion 101</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>  <!-- end #nav  -->
    <div class="menu-trigger">MODASearch <span>The Fashion Directory</span> <i class="fa fa-bars "></i></div>
</div>  <!-- end #menu  -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

responsive CSS:

```
.menu-trigger{display:block;}
.my-menu {display:none; }
.nav-expanded{display:block;}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".my-menu").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display','');
        });

    });

});
```

followed the following tutorial link if anyone is interested [tutorial](http://learnwebcode.com/responsive-web-design-navigation-menu-tutorial/#comment-49314)